# How can I remove gap in String in Java

Tags: java, trim

Here is my code:

```
package test;

public class Stringtest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "     love   y  ou    !!    ";
    String b = a.trim();
    b.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    System.out.println(b);
}
}
```

But the result is still:"love    y ou   !!". It just remove the white space at the start and the end of the string. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: It seems there is no *way* to dertmine that "y ou" should be "you"

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. b.replaceAll() returns a new String with the result

Comment: System.out.println(b.replaceAll("\\s+",""));

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable which means you can't change them. That is why `replaceAll` doesn't affect original string, but creates new one with replaced values which you need to store somewhere, possibly even in original reference.

So try with

```
b = b.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Comment: Silly me :P . Thank you guys so much for quick answer. Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to vote up for you guys ;)

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll` method of String will return back string after removing all the spaces and as String is immutable, so assign the outcome of replaceAll back to b like:

```
b = b.replaceAll("\\s+","");//Note you dont need to trim if you want to replace every spaces.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following and you'll understand what you have done.

```
System.out.println(b.replaceAll("\\s+",""));
```

`string.replace()` returns the replaced string

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to store the substring which return from `replaceAll` method.

try

```
b = b.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```